# <style> tag need ; at ending or not

Tags: html, css, tags

```
<div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:70%"> //width:70% no ;
```

or

```
<div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:70%;"> //width:70% with ;
```

Some tutorial have ';' in there example code but some tutorial don't have ';' at the end. I try 2 of them and show same output. my question is which one is correct or which one is best practice.

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are multiple styles (f.e. height: 20px and width: 30px) you have to write a ';'. But if there is only one style-option, it won't have to write it (but it looks better ;-) )

Answer (score 0):

As Adagi Said, its no need for a single property styles, and also it not needed for the last property of the multiple style option.